# Async Knockout Bindings

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

What are the implications/potential problems of completing a binding asynchronously?

Consider the following binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.widget = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel)
    {
        var values = valueAccessor();

        //depending on type, delegate binding work to another function
        factory.getWidget(values.type)
        .done(function (widget) {
            widget.bind(element, values.settings, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel);
        });

        //widget.bind is responsible for all children
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };

    }
};
```

What are the potential problems that may occur as a result of the `init` function returning before the binding "work", which includes DOM manipulation, has actually been completed?

I can't clearly see any specific scenario that would cause a problem, but I want to see if anyone else knows something in the way knockout works that may cause problems later.

Comment: This is a pretty complex topic, but in essence you can do it.  We did a lot of work on this and related things in limn: https://github.com/wikimedia/limn/tree/master/src/util/knockout

Comment: Btw @Milimetric, the link really helped me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was recently working on a similar problem. I have created a custom binding for jsTree  that I'm using in my web application. So the UI is -> root -> children -> children's children and so on (on the left)... And for each entity, there is a table that shows some related data (on the right) and a form field showing the fields of the entity. Also, I'm loading both the tree and the data table asynchronously hitting the server with an AJAX call each time the user clicks on a tree node. However, I do have both the init and update methods filled out in my binding handlers.

To help you understand the context a little better, lets take USA as the root node in my tree, USA has many states (root's children) and each state has many counties and so on. Many of the fields inside the root object (USA) will most likely be different than the fields inside its children entities (states, in this case). I'm sorry I can't think of fields that would be there in USA and not in a State, but I'm hoping you get the point.

Also, I have an observable called 'currentSelectedObject' in my VM that gets updated each time the user clicks on a different node in the tree, I make an AJAX call to get the object, and I have a method called replace current object that handles changing the current selected object.. And as mentioned before, parent and child objects have (mostly) different fields. Here's where I ran into a lot of problems. In my html I bind the values of the element like this:

```
data-bind: value: currentSelectedObject().xyz
```

Now lets say the user clicks on a different object that doesn't have the field 'xyz,' I used to get this error:

```
can't read property xyz of undefined.
```

I got that error because for an extremely small time, the currenySelectedObject has changed and the view (the HTML template) hasn't. I thought the change would be atomic but apparently it isn't. The way I fixed this was by actually updating the current object in the success callback of my AJAX call.

```
self.replaceCurrentObject = function(type, id, callback){
    server.getObject(type, id,     // server.js is an abstraction over the data layer
        function(returnObject){    // corresponds to: success: function(data){...}
            self.currentSelectedObject(returnObject);
        }
    if(callback) callback();      // to handle other table related stuff
}
```